# "Provider cannot be found" while creating ADODB connection

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

When executing my Excel sheet with the VBA macro, I’m getting this issue Provider cannot be found. Any idea on this will be helpful

Getting error as

> Run-time error 3706 Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.

Code line is

```
Set connection = CreateObject(“ADODB.Connection”)
```

[image: Error image]

Answer (score 0):

It isn't finding the ADODB provider. Try using early binding by setting a reference using Tools,References in the VB editor and ticking "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects" (+ whatever version nunber you have, if you have more than one pick the highest number)

You can then write

```
 Dim Conn as ADODB.Connection
 Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
```

Comment: Hi I have already included Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library in the reference. But still facing the same issue.

Comment: Are you still using createobject? Make sure your using what @HarassedDad said

`Dim Conn as ADODB.Connection`
`Set conn = New ADODB.Connection`

Comment: I have tried that as well but I’m getting conn as blank.

Comment: One thing I want to bring to the notice that the code was working fine. Recently I’m facing issue. I’m not sure but may be driver missing for connecting to data source.

Comment: If the library is missing then the entry in references will show MISSING next to it. Selecting the reference will also show the path to where it's supposed to be: usually C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ado